# keras_rl DQN agent - all policies select_action() func return value of 0 or 1

Tags: python, keras, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, keras-rl

I am trying to setup a reinforcement learning project using Gym & kears_rl.

**Description:**

Given a numbers in a range `(100, 200)`, I want the agent to alert me when a number is close to the limits, lets say between `0%-10%` and `90%-100%` of the quantiles.

*Reward:*

sample in quantile (0, 0.1), reward is (+1)

sample in quantile (0.1, 0.9), reward is (-1)

sample in quantile (0.9, 1), reward is (+1)

**The agent need to learn the 10% & 90% limits values.**

```
low = np.array([100])
high = np.array([200])
self.action_space = spaces.Box(low=low, high=high, dtype=np.intt32)
self.observation_space = spaces.Box(low=low, high=high, dtype=np.int32)
```

**main.py info:**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
        env = Env(max_steps=100)

        nb_actions = env.action_space.shape[0]  # equal to 100

        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(1,) + env.observation_space.shape))
        model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

        memory = SequentialMemory(limit=50000, window_length=1)
        policy = BoltzmannQPolicy()

        # Create DQN agent
        dqn = DQNAgent(model=env.model,
                       memory=memory,
                       policy=policy,
                       nb_actions=nb_actions,
                       nb_steps_warmup=10,
                       target_model_update=1e-2)

        # Compile the DQN agent
        dqn.compile(Adam(lr=1e-3), metrics=['mae'])

        # Okay, now it's time to learn something!
        dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=50000, visualize=False, verbose=1)
```

**Questions\issues:**

On the fit function (rl/core.py:169), the action I get equal to zero. it should be between [100, 200]. Why is that? I expect the action to be within the action_space but I see that all policies return a value of 0 or 1. How I suppose to use the value in the env.step() func?

my code is based on the following examples:

[OpenAI-Gym cartpole.py](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/classic_control/cartpole.py)

[keras_rl dqn_cartpole.py](https://github.com/keras-rl/keras-rl/blob/master/examples/dqn_cartpole.py)

[OpenAI-Gym hottercolder.py environment](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/toy_text/hotter_colder.py)

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.